# How do I run Command and Conquer Generals (Zero Hour) in windowed mode via Origin?

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I've got the combination game of C&C Generals with and without Zero Hour on Origin, however the game is pretty old and doesn't work well with modern hardware, so I want to run it in windowed mode.

I should be able to pass `-win` to it via command line arguments, but if I try that, it starts a launcher which doesn't pass the command line arguments along.

I've tried starting the game without the launcher... but that just starts the launcher again.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to run it _through_ Origin? If it's downloaded, you should have access to the .exe in your program files. You can create a shortcut for that with the windowed argument as described [here](http://www.cnclabs.com/generals/zerohour/command-line-arguments.aspx), then run the game using that shortcut. That should skip the launcher and go straight to the game.

Comment: As noted above that doesn't help, because that just starts the launcher again (the launcher not being Origin, the launcher being the thing that lets you decide generals or zero hour)

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't realize you had tried that already. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use GenPatcher by Legionnaire. It will patch the game for windows 10/11 etc and create shortcuts for windowed mode.

If you don't want to do that:

1. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\EA Games\Command & Conquer Generals Zero Hour"
2. Right click `generals.exe` and click `Create Shortcut`.
3. Once the shortcut is created, right click it and click `properties`.
4. add `-win` to the end of the `Target` field. Make sure you add it after the closing `"`
5. Double click the shortcut.

[image: Screenshot of the target field]